# PHP script outputs XML Sitemap

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap

On my webroot, I have a file, say, `foo.php` that outputs a valid XML Sitemap. In robots.txt, I have something like:

```
Sitemap: http://SomeDomain.com/foo.php
```

Will the sitemap be found by Google, etc.?

Comment: I would think so. There is one way to find out. Have you tried submitting it via Google's Search Console?

Comment: @closetnoc If you submit it via GSC then Google will undoubtedly "find it" (providing it is indeed a valid XML Sitemap), but isn't part of the question... will it find if it is (only) referenced in `robots.txt`? (However, you would _need_ to submit it via GSC if you want GSC to report on it. But just because GSC doesn't report on it, doesn't mean it's not found it.)

Comment: @w3dk I read the question as this: Because I used a non-standard file extension, would Google not find, but use my PHP script to generate a script? The one way to know if G would have heart burn or not is to test it.

Comment: @closetnoc True, I did read it that way as well at first but then thought there must be something more the question? Maybe not?

Comment: @w3dk I view this as a try it and see scenario. It would not hurt. Still, I recommend that people submit any sitemap through the Search Console anyway. Same with Bing. Why? Why not! Couldn't hurt. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

A .xml extension is not required, it can even be a GET parameter triggering the sitemap.

See http://www.sitemaps.org/: No specification for a particular file extension.

Comment: And Google supports the `Sitemap:` directive in the `robots.txt` file, so it's reasonable to assume that Google will find it. Reference: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt